# How to get client ip in an ssh session?

Tags: ssh

I have a /etc/ssh/sshrc file that emails me after every every SSH login. It uses $SSH_CLIENT to get the IP address, but with all the methods I try, I get that the IP is ::1. How can I get the real IP of an ssh client and why is it giving me the IP of localhost? I just realized the problem was caused by sslh, which forwards all ssh connections from port 443 to 22. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Could you edit your post to include the contents of your sshrc file?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/editing-help, learn formatting, and then post text instead of screenshots, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for everyone that helped. I found that the problem was sslh, and the solution was using transparent forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

With command

```
sudo netstat -at | grep ssh
```

you can see who is connected on `SSH` server.
This can write to some .log file

```
sudo netstat -at | grep ssh >> ssh.log
```

Or you can create script, something like this

```
nano ssh.sh
```

or give some diferent name

```
#!/bin/bash
date >> ssh.log
netstat -at | grep ssh >> ssh.log
```

give `chmod 777`. This script will first write date and ssh sessions
This log cen send to email ....

Comment: Thank you, but I still can't find the actual IP of the ssh client.

Comment: Give me output of command `netstat -at | grep ssh`